# What does ConnectionShutdownException mean and how do I prevent it?

Tags: java, apache, exception

I am trying to use apache's httpclient Java library. But I keep getting massive numbers of ConnectionShutdownException.

The javadocs for the exception are not very helpful:

"Signals that the connection has been shut down or released back to the the connection pool"

Can anyone explain what this means, and what I can do to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

I found this: ConnectionShutdownException is a subclass of IllegalStateException.
'Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.' Based on this, your computer is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation. You can solve it by checking your computer or getting a new one.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html?is-external=true

Comment: Getting a new one?